# How to set cookie name in a Spring Boot application running in a standalone Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, cookies, spring-boot

I tried different ways to set a customized cookie name. But none is working in my configuration.

I have a Spring Boot application which is running in a standalone Tomcat.

I tried to set the cookie name in the `SpringBootApplication` class which is derived from `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@Value("${session.cookie.name}")
private String sessionCookieName;

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName(sessionCookieName);
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
```

Also I tried to define a bean as `DefaultCookieSerializer`:

```
@Value("${session.cookie.name}")
private String sessionCookieName;

@Bean
public DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer(){
    DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    defaultCookieSerializer.setCookieName(sessionCookieName);
    return defaultCookieSerializer;
}
```

But nothing is working so far, I always get the default `JSESSONID` instead of my configured `session.cookie.name`

Are there any other ways to customize the cookie name?

Comment: Add a [`TomcatContainerCustomizer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatContextCustomizer.html) as a bean and use the `setSessionCookieName` method on the `Context` (passed in) to change the name of the cookie.

Comment: Please add your full `Application` class instead of a snippet.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question not as an update to your question. This will help future visitors understand and will cause less confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the TomcatContextCustomizer as suggested. But I think it does not work, when you deploy your application as a WAR-File because it is just for the embedded tomcat.

I resolved the issue by adding a web.xml. In the folder src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. I'm not really satisfied with this solution, because I don't want a web.xml in my spring boot application. But it works...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      metadata-complete="true">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
             <name>CUSTOM_SESSION_ID</name>
             <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

If there are any better solutions let me know

Answer (score 1):

In the spring boot application. You can rename the `JESSIONID` by setting your custom name in `application.properties` file as below:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=Your_custome_name
```

It works fine for me.